# What is the physics behind the cooling of the atmosphere during a total solar eclipse?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, eclipse

Consider the Great American Eclipse (The total solar eclipse over America in 2017).  Observed atmospheric temperature drops were in the range of 3 C to 8 C in a matter of minutes.  Surface temperatures dropped about the same amount as did the atmosphere, best I can tell.  I'm lacking data on that though.

Other total solar eclipse observations universally (to my knowledge) document temperature drops.

In any event, such temperature drops represent a massive amount of energy presumably lost to space in a very short amount of time.

**Edit:**

**How does this energy in the atmosphere radiate to space?**

- The Energy must be radiated to space
- Greenhouse gases can absorb kinetic energy from O2 and N2
- Only greenhouse gases can radiate at atmospheric temperatures
- Without solar input, the atmosphere cools because greenhouse gases radiate more energy than the earth can supply

**Is that correct?**

Comment: There must be a massive energy flux out to space, to balance the massive energy influx from the Sun.  When the latter is suddenly removed, the balance shifts suddenly

Comment: I’m not quite sure what the question is here. Are you asking whether the mechanism for temperature drops during an eclipse is different from the mechanism for making it get colder at night?

Comment: Energy transfer can only occur via conduction, convection, or radiation in the atmosphere.

The only gasses capable of significant transfer of energy in the atmosphere are greenhouse gases. O2 and N2 radiation at atmospheric temperatures are negligible.

In cool dry air, the only significant greenhouse gas that could be cooling this body of air that fast is CO2.

Can CO2 actually cool the atmosphere?  How does that square with CO2 trapping heat?

Answer (score 1):

Water is the main GHG in the terrestrial atmosphere. But that's besides the point. The surface air temperature is set by the balance of visible transparent irradiation and diffusive infrared re-radiation.

However, Earth's infrared optical depth due to all the Greenhouse gases is only $\tau_{\rm IR}\approx2$, so it is not surprising that a cooling effect can happen in minutes via radiation. The infrared radiation simply diffuses away once it is not resupplied anymore.
Same as if it were suddenly to become night.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the  τIR≈2.  Various sources give far lower values.  Diamond is supposed to be the highest at 2.42...

Comment: @PaulSnow Without greenhouse gases, the atmosphere would be transparent to the outgoing infrared radiation, and hence cool maximally. It would reach radiative equilibrium  with the surface only at $T=T_{\rm eq}$. When adding GHG, your cooling surface, which cools with the power $L = 4\pi r^2_{\tau=1} T^4_{\tau=1}$ from the $\tau=1$ transition, will move up the adiabatic gradient towards lower $T_{\tau=1}$ (while $r_{\tau=1}$ only changes very little), hence decreasing L, which means that radiation must be left behind. This is the greenhouse effect.

Comment: @PaulSnow Not sure what you're talking about. To avoid confusion I specifically said "the infrared optical depth". Look up the definition if you're unsure. But essentially, when computing the integral over densities $\rho$, path length r and opacity of the gas mix $\kappa$ you end up with $\tau= \int \rho(r) \kappa(r,T,\rho) dr$ of approx. $\tau \approx 1.93$ for a saturated steam water atmosphere on Earth, and $\tau\approx 1.98$ when adding ~300ppm CO2 into the mix. This $\tau$ is enough to raise the temperature above $T_{eq}$ by a few tens of K, but also the diffusion time is not long.

Comment: I understand roughly the radiation component of warming the earth, but I struggle with the conduction and convection components.  On an earth with atmosphere of only O2 and N2 and other non-greenhouse gases, the atmosphere would still absorb heat from the surface during the day, but would be unable to shed that heat at night through IR radiation, and be too cool to shed that heat via higher bandwidths. 

Since conduction only involves a few cms of air at the surface, heat in the atmosphere would be trapped.

Comment: It also seems to me that without CO2, calm dry air under an eclipse could not cool.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @PaulSnow: Wrong and wrong. If you want non-greenhouse gases, i.e. infrared transparent gases, then the $t_{IR}=1$ surface is the physical surface and your luminosity is the one you get is $L=4\pi r^2_p T^4_{\rm surf}$. This $L$ will affect the surface material however, not the gas. The gas will cool via the few weak lines that non-GHG gases posses and exchange heat with the surface via conduction. Gas temperature and surface temperature will take a long time to equilibrate.

Comment: @PaulSnow Without CO2, and under an otherwise identical atmosphere, convection still acts during a solar eclipse, until the entropy gradient in the atmosphere reaches zero. During all this time however, all radiative windows are open from the surface (especially without CO2 the 15 $\mu$m window) and therefore with only $\tau_{IR}\approx 2$ radiation remains relatively important for cooling. Remember that radiation is still transported in a convective zone, its importance (or fluxes F) decreases only as $F \propto 1/\tau$.

Comment: Calm dry air under an eclipse cannot cool with convection alone since there is no supply of cool air to replace the warm air.  We ate talking about 5 C here.  Without CO2 there is no way to radiate heat to space from billions of square meters of air.  Certainly the surface can cool (it has all kinds of materials that can radiate) but without water and CO2 the air can't. And the air can't conduct to the surface that fast.  Not in calm air, certainly.

Comment: "Without CO2, and under an otherwise identical atmosphere, convection still acts during a solar eclipse, until the entropy gradient in the atmosphere reaches zero."---  are you saying the air under a total eclipse in calm dry air is cooled by convection?  Even without CO2?  I'd say that 10^12 kjoules of energy in 3 billion sq meters of air (umbra up 10 meters) can't be removed by convection.

Comment: " I'd say that 10^12 kjoules of energy in 3 billion sq meters of air (umbra up 10 meters) can't be removed by convection." Do you have any notion of how strong convective fluxes are? Radiative fluxes? Quoting big numbers means nothing if you can't translate them into cooling times. Hence the optical depth argument. And as long as there is a negative entropy gradient, the convective instability, a fundamental buoyant  instability, operates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146380/discussion-between-paulsnow-and-atmosphericprisonescape).